# Frobenius automorphism for abelian/non abelian number fields extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $E/F$ be an extension of number fields. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be an ideal of $E$ that does non ramify in $E$. We know that since $\mathfrak{p}$ is non ramified, for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$ of $E$ that divides $\mathfrak{p}$ we have an isomorphism of groups between the inertia group of $\mathfrak{P}$ and the Galois group of $(\mathcal{O}_E/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p})$
$$G_{\mathfrak{P}}\cong \mathcal{G}\Big((\mathcal{O}_E/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p})\Big).$$
Since on the right we have the Galois group of an extension of finite field, we have the classic Frobenius endomorphism that sends
$$\begin{align}
x \mapsto x^{[\mathcal{O}_E/\mathfrak{P}:\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}]}
\end{align}$$
so, by the isomorphism of groups we have that there is an automorphism of $E/F$ such that
$$\sigma_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}(x) \equiv x^{[\mathcal{O}_E/\mathfrak{P}:\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}]} \qquad \text{ for all $x\in \mathcal{O}_E$}.$$
Now the problem comes. In the book "Automorphic Forms and Representations" of Daniel Bump, at paragraph 1.8 there is an interesting period

> We would like it if $\sigma_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}$ depend only on $\mathfrak{p}$. This is the case if $E/F$ is abelian. If the extension $E/F$ is non abelian, $\sigma_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}$ depends on the choice of the prime $\mathfrak{P}$, but only up to conjugacy

I know that $\mathcal{G}(E/F)$ acts transitively on the set of all prime ideals $\mathfrak{P}$ lying above $\mathfrak{p}$ but it's not clear to me why the abelianity of $\mathcal{G}(E/F)$ works with the automorphism that we found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau \in \mathcal G(E/F)$. Then I claim that we have $$\tau \sigma_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}\tau^{-1}=\sigma_{\tau(\mathfrak{P})|\mathfrak{p}}$$

First let $\sigma \in G_{\mathfrak{P}}$ and $\tau$ as above. Then we get $\sigma(\mathfrak{P})=\mathfrak{P}$ which implies $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\tau(\mathfrak{P}))=\tau(\mathfrak{P})$, thus $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} \in G_{\tau(\mathfrak{P})}$.

Let $f=[\mathcal O_E/\mathfrak{P}:\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak{p}]=[\mathcal O_E/\tau(\mathfrak{P}):\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak{p}]$

Now let $x \in \mathcal O_E$, then $\tau^{-1}(x)^f-\sigma_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}\tau^{-1}(x) \in \mathfrak{P}$ which implies that $x^f-\tau\sigma_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}\tau^{-1}(x) \in \tau(\mathfrak{P})$. This proves the claim.

Now with the claim and the fact that the Galois group acts transitively on prime ideals above $\mathfrak{p}$, this implies that Frobenius elements are well-defined up to conjugacy  in general, and this implies they are well-defined in the abelian case.